# How to complete purchase with eBay trading API

Tags: ebay-api

I was able to make an offer using PlaceOfferRequest (XML). What should I do in order to complete the purchase and update the shipping address to where he/she should ship the Item?

I'm using XML in order to post the request.

Comment: Wondering about the same. I suspect that there's no way to make payments through the eBay API, but I also can't find any information to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't find any official resource stating that completing purchases isn't possible, I'm 99% sure that its simply not possible. All you can do is redirect the user to the payments page, using this template for the URL:

`http://payments.${DOMAIN}/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?CheckoutProcessor&item=${Item.ItemID}&transactionId=${TransactionID}`

Where DOMAIN could be, for example, "sandbox.ebay.de" or just "ebay.com".